# How to automatically get Bearer Token using REST Assured

Tags: java, oauth, postman, rest-assured, bearer-token

I am using Postman currently to generate Bearer Token, which I am using in my automated tests. Now I would like to automate also the Bearer Token generation process too using REST Assured in Java. Please help me. Thanks.

[image]

```
Response response =
      given()
          .auth()
          .oauth(
              "n0pCrq5SPgraZ3CyY0Nd",
              "xvvx-LVd5dszLi9OO_1qjbU4eUQ4dXwLrDZN7oioSITr_EXrgsyyOvPvZmv85Ew2",
              "",
              "",
                  "HMAC-SHA256")
          .when()
          .get(url)
          .then()
          .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
          .extract()
          .response();
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your POSTMAN setup which you have to generate the bearer token and we can help

Answer (score 2):

This is working. Thanks @wilfred clement.

```
public static String getOauthToken(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String endpoint ) {

log.info("GET ACCESS TOKEN=" + endpoint);
URI uri = null;
try {
  uri = new URI(endpoint);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
  log.error("Not proper oauth url=" + endpoint);
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

ValidatableResponse res = given()
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .auth().oauth(consumerKey,
                consumerSecret,
                "",
                "")
        .body("{\"grantType\": \"client_credentials\"}").when().post(uri).then();

int responseCode = res.extract().statusCode();

if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == responseCode) {
  String token = res.extract().jsonPath().get("accessToken").toString();
  log.info("Auth token=" + token);
  return token;
} else {
  String msg = "Access token retrieve failed. Http response code=" + responseCode;
  log.error(msg);
  throw new RuntimeException(msg);
}
```

}